# Show the latest content in the view by created at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am able to sort the users by their `created_at` date by using `@users.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.each do |user|`

I need help with sorting the subscribe users by the subscription `created_at` date.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    <% if user.subscription %>
      |<%= user.subscription.id %> | <%= user.subscription.plan.name %> |  <%= user.subscription.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %> | <% if user.subscription.stripe_customer_token.nil? %> PAYPAL <% end %>
<% if user.subscription.paypal_recurring_profile_token.nil? %> STRIPE  <% end %>
```

I think I need to change all of that code in the view, as I should really only be showing users that are inside the Subscription table. Instead I am pulling from the Users table, and then grabbing their subscription information. Current code is of course showing Users without subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort_by can take a block.

```
@users.sort_by {|user| user.subscription.created_at}
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Just put it in the chain

```
@users.sort_by {|user| user.subscription.created_at}.reverse.each do |user|
```

This works assuming Subscription belongs_to User and User either has_one, or has_many Subscriptions.  Which I can tell by your view it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired outcome when you are querying database:

```
User.includes(:subscription).order("subscriptions.created_at DESC")
```

This query will eagerly load the subscription records for users, and will sort the records by subscription's `created_at` field. If you are not already eagerly loading the subscription records using `includes(:subscription)`, this approach will eliminate a lot of queries as it prevents your database to be hit each time you call `user.subscription` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on controller action with something like this:

```
@users = User.includes(:suscription).order('subscriptions.created_at desc')
```

I hope it help.